# How do you create a 19khz sound wave with 2 adjustable acoustic sources with a range of 20~40 khz?

Tags: acoustics

Found on a quiz book about rudimentary science. I didn't manage to get the answer before getting on board of an airplane, and it still bugs me till today.

I thought I found a solution for it but once I put it down on paper with a few graphs drawn and equations penned I found that I was helplessly wrong.

So, how do you do it?

Comment: Look into [beats](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)).  I'd also suggest looking up "beat frequency".

Comment: I think the quiz book is misleading. Sure, the answer below gives a waveform of $\cos 19kHz*t \cos 59kHz*t$ but it will never be perceived as a tone at 19kHz. It will always sound like two tones of 20kHz and 39kHz.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP This doesn't say "a tone perceived as 19 kHz".  It's looking for a sound wave with a specific frequency.  By superimposing two waves with different frequencies you can get a beat frequency equal to the difference; it doesn't matter how the brain percieves it, the sound _is_ a sound wave with a 19 kHz frequency.

Comment: @Jmac would you perhaps go as far as to say that we have a sound wave of 19, 20, 39, and 59 kHz all at the same time then?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP If you can find repeated oscillations in the amplitude at those frequencies, sure.  The question asks for "a 19 kHz sound wave", it doesn't say that it's the primary frequency of the wave or any other characteristics; just that the wave will have a periodic element with a frequency of 19 kHz.  If you set up a beat that occurs 19 thousand times a second, you've created a sound wave with a frequency of 19 kHz; seems to check the boxes to me.

Comment: @Jmac it has a node 19k times per second but it's period is certainly not 1/19000th of a second. Idk, this feels as permissive to me as to say that a 2Hz wave has a frequency of 1Hz simply because there a period of that wave *is* 1s. As in thr analogy i drew below, I'd need the wave to excite a 19kHz eigenmode before I admit it to be 19khz

Comment: @LLlAMnYP That's all well and good if you want a more-strict definition.  Given the information we have and the lack of strict definitions, I think it's pretty obvious that the "audible beat frequency" is what you would want here.  Sometimes it's important to take a step back and get a feel for the intention of the question.  Given the constraints of "adjustable sources between 20 kHz and 40 kHz"; it's seems glaringly obvious that the intention is to create a beat at 19 kHz.  Complicating it with strict mathematical definitions seems like pedantry at best when the intention is so apparent.

Comment: @Jmac quoting OP *but once I put it down on paper with a few graphs drawn and equations penned I found that I was helplessly wrong.* it seems to me that he reached the same doubts as I. I suppose the intent of his quiz book is clear, but it's probably not wrong to acknowledge his confusion as well justified.

Comment: @JMac IMO it's not "pedantry" at all. The differences between combining different frequencies by *linear* and *nonlinear* processes are subtle. Human hearing and sound perception (done by the brain!) are both *nonlinear.*  "What you measure with a microphone and a spectrum analyser" is not necessarily the same as "what you hear". Failure to understand that can lead beginners into to serious confusion at best, or serious (but apparently unconfused) mistakes at worst. If you want examples to demonstrate this, read some of the other answers and comments!

Answer (score 0):

In acoustics, a beat is an interference pattern between two sounds of slightly different frequencies, perceived as a periodic variation in volume whose rate is the difference of the two frequencies.

So to create a 19 kHz sound you should use for example a 20 kHz source and a 39 kHz source.

Comment: See, that's the thing. You have a 19kHz variation of the volume of a 59kHz tone, not the other way around.

Comment: when you say "a 19kHz variation of the volume of a 59kHz tone" it means that there is a superposition of two waves (19 kHz and 59 kHz) in the concidered point of space.

Comment: I can't agree with that. If you look at the waveform, you'll see that it crosses zero 2*59 times per ms. There is still only a superposition of 20kHz and 39kHz, if you don't agree, we need to define what a wave of x frequency is in the first place. The result of a fourier transform is least ambiguous, I think. But I guess we could draw an analogy with two-photon processes as well and see if a Raman mode of x-y frequency can br excited by photons at frequencies x and y.

Comment: about AM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation

Comment: here is the formula for AM: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/3ba6c481488d128f98d75d102d31147c507a0b6e    so you can see that mixing 20 kHz and 39 kHz we get three different components:  the carrier wave c(t) = 39 kHz which would be unchanged, and two sine waves (sidebands) with frequencies 20 kHz above and 20 kHz below the carrier frequency fc

Comment: Should I understand the silence as a sign of consensus? )

Comment: A lack of it, I guess, re: the discussion under the op:-)